# htaccess URL not found

Tags: php, .htaccess, friendly-url

I have an **.htaccess** file and code in it:

```
#command_players
RewriteRule ^command_players/([0-9]+)?$ command_players.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
```

My login page should redirect to command_players.php page when the user input is correct:

```php
if (password_verify($_POST['pass'], $results['pass'])) {
    $_SESSION['command']= 'ok';
    $_SESSION['id'] = $results['id'];
    redirect("command_players/$results[id]/");
}
```

But I get an error like:

> The requested URL /site/command_players/18/ was not found on this server,

when `/site/command_players.php` works.

I am not good in htaccess, what I do wrong?

Comment: Your RewriteRule contains neither the `site/` prefix nor the `/` suffix you have in the request URL `…players/18/`

Comment: Try this: `RewriteRule ^command_players/([0-9]+)?$ /site/command_players.php?id=$1 [NC,L]`

Comment: Having a script file with the “same” name (minus the suffix) as a folder can often lead to trouble in these situations; try to disable MultiViews.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the slash (`/`) in your regular expression in the htaccess file, as follows.

`?` means "zero or one of the previous", so `/?` means "no slashes or one", which corresponds to the pattern you described.

```
#command_players
RewriteRule ^command_players/([0-9]+)/?$ command_players.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
```

**Useful resources**

- https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html commonly used rules/tips
- https://regexr.com tool to test regexes

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I used:                                                                                               
#command_players
RewriteRule ^command_players/([0-9]+)/?$ command_players.php?id=$1 [NC,L]  just copy your suggestion, but unfortunately the problem is persists.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was about folder and I miss '/' in login redirect. Now it works:

```
#command_players
RewriteRule ^command_players/([0-9]+)/?$ site/command_players.php?id=$1 [NC,L]



 if (password_verify($_POST['pass'], $results['pass'])) {
                                $_SESSION['command']= 'ok';
                                $_SESSION['id'] = $results['id'];
                                //redirect("command/list.php/$results[id]/");
                                redirect("/command_players/{$results['id']}/");
                            }
```